# Python 3 контрольная сумма HEX строки

Tags: python-3.x

Добрый день!

Возникла необходимость эмуляции протокола синхронизации времени BINARYt с компьютера на синхронизируемое устройство. Протокол этот был придуман разработчиками ПС-161 (приемник) и более нигде не используется. Проблем с формированием HEX строки (которая содержит дату и время нет) нет, но есть проблема с расчетом контрольной суммы этой HEX строчки.

Вот пример строки: 57 F1 0F 9A A8 B7 00 08 0B 19 10 00 00 00 00 00 11 0B 15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

5 и 6 числа - это контрольная сумма A8 и B7
По-идее она считается так: суммируются все числа строки (за исключением самой контрольной суммы) - получается 32 битовое число. Далее складываем старшие и младшие 16 бит этого числа - получаем новое 16 битовое число. Старшие 8 бит - это B7, а младшие A8 (в данном примере).
Что я делаю:

```
data = bytearray.fromhex('57 F1 0F 9A 00 00 00 08 0B 19 10 00 00 00 00 00 11 0B 15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00')

c_sum = sum(data)
```

И на выходе 0x25e. Чтобы далее я не делал с этой суммой у меня никак не выходит эта контрольная сумма.

На C код по ее расчету выглядит так (от 100% работает):

```
void ByteStream_ComputeCS(void)
{
       int i;
       DWORD cs = 0;
       for (i = 0; i < ByteStream[2] + 3; i++)
       {
               if (i != 2) cs += *((WORD*)ByteStream + i);
       }
       cs = (cs & 0xFFFF) + (cs >> 16);
       ByteStream[4] = (BYTE)cs;
       ByteStream[5] = (BYTE)(cs >> 8);
}
```

Тут контрольную сумму просто обходят и не суммируют (я же просто приравнял ее 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На входе в Си коде у вас  последовательность байт, а не их шестнадцатеричное представление в виде читаемой (ascii) строки (hexdump).

Вот буквальный перевод Си кода на Питон:

```py
import array

a = array.array('H', data[:2*(data[2]+3)])
cs = sum(x for i, x in enumerate(a) if i != 2) & 0xFFFF_FFFF
cs = (cs & 0xFFFF) + (cs >> 16)
data[4:6] = (cs & 0xFFFF).to_bytes(2, 'little')
```

Можно использовать `cs = sum(a)`, если `data[4:6] == b'\0\0'` у вас на входе. Если дополнительно `len(data) == 2*(data[2]+3)` (нет лишних байт), то можно без копирования обойтись:

```
cs = sum(memoryview(data).cast('H')) & 0xFFFF_FFFF
cs = (cs & 0xFFFF) + (cs >> 16)
data[4:6] = (cs & 0xFFFF).to_bytes(2, 'little')
```

`& 0xFFFF_FFFF` используется на случай, если `sum(a)` переполняет DWORD.

Так как `int` имеет бесконечную точность в Питоне, то приходится вручную следить, чтобы значения оставались в рамках, допустимых для соответствующих Си типов.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Отличное рабочее решение!

Answer (score 0):

Понял в чем была проблема:
Нужно суммировать 57F1 + 0F9A + .... а не 57 + F1 + 0F + 9A +...как это делает код выше в вопросе.

Я нашел такое решение: 
Нужно перевести HEX  строку в байты следующим образом

```
def HexToByte(hexStr):

    bytes = []

    hexStr = ''.join(hexStr.split(" "))

    for i in range(0, len(hexStr), 4):
        bytes.append(int(hexStr[i:i + 4], 16))

    return bytes
```

И уже потом суммировать.
Вопрос - можно ли это как-то проще сделать?

Comment: Да тот же `bytearray.fromhex` можно использовать, только байты циклом попарно обрабатывать.